# What is the difference between these conditionals?

Tags: past-perfect

> If the party hadn't stopped, I would not have felt so awake.
>
> If the party hadn't stopped, I would not feel so awake.

Can I use the first sentence as a reference to the present time?Or the second would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For it to continue into the present

> If the party hadn't stopped, I would not **feel** so awake.

is best.